# FileNotFoundException while copying data to SD Card - Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-widget

Following is the code which I use to copy a folder containing a txt file. The folder resides in assets folder of my application. While I copy , I get File not found exception in the line *out = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);*

I get this working perfectly, when I save this to /data/data folder; ie; internal memory. I have checked the SD card state and it shows mounted.

```
public class CpyAsset extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    copyFileOrDir("edu1");//directory name in assets
}
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
private void copyFileOrDir(String path) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    String assets[] = null;
    try {
        assets = assetManager.list(path);
        if (assets.length == 0) {
            copyFile(path);
        } else {
            File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
            if (!dir.exists()){
                System.out.println("Created directory"+sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
                boolean result = dir.mkdir();
                System.out.println("Result of directory creation"+result);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < assets.length; ++i) {
                copyFileOrDir(path + "/" + assets[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception in copyFileOrDir"+ex);
    }
}

private void copyFile(String filename) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(filename);
        String newFileName = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+filename;
        out = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in copyFile"+e);
    }

}
}
```

**Exception**

```
01-01 06:13:34.783: INFO/System.out(11334): Exception in copyFilejava.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/edu1/anees.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The folder(and the content) I try to copy is in assets/edu1/abc.txt

Can someone please let me know what causes this as I cannot find any obvious reasons for the same? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you set the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest?

Comment: yes, I have set the permission `    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>`

Comment: should not it be if (!(assets.length == 0)) { ?

Comment: Add e.printstacktrace to your exception handler so it stops hiding the error details. Also add logging of the files attempted by copyFile, and post the whole log.

Answer (score 2):

You are always trying to create the external storage root dir in this part:

```
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
if (!dir.exists()){
            System.out.println("Created directory"+sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
            boolean result = dir.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Result of directory creation"+result);
}
```

so you are not creating the folder `edu1/` and the creation of the file `anees.txt` in that folder will fail.

Comment: tried as you and Amal suggested and exception is not there now. But I cannot see the file in  /mnt/sdcard/edu1/anees.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try it out this way.......

```
File f = new File("/sdcard/assets/edu1/abc.txt");

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
```

Comment: It will create a file name abc.txt on sdcard at location assets/edu1, and will write by taking the input from the source...now source can be Console, File...etc...

Answer (score 1):

in your code you check if the sdcard path is exist while you should check for your path which result in the dir "edu1" is never created try use this instead

```
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+path);
```

Comment: Now the exception is gone, but I do not see the file in the path path /mnt/sdcard/edu1/anees.txt . Why?

Comment: @user1400538 you should see it I already tried the code with my modification and found the files and it should work correctly